# Does a Shell Script Execute Commands Sequentially?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a python script which is a little unstable and gives an SSL error every now and then. The exception is raised by some function buried deep within some library so there is essentially no fix to it.

I have implemented a hacky solution by creating a shell script with a while loop that runs a large number of times and executing the python script from within that loop.

Now what I'm hoping is that as an iteration of the loop starts and the script is executed, the loop inside the shell script stays where it is until the python script fails and the next iteration of the loop re-executes the script and so on.

Is doing it like this efficient? Is there a better way to do it? and most importantly is it correct?

Comment: Why can't you catch the exception, fix the script or fix the library?

Comment: This doesn't sound very secure. Are you using a recent version of Python 3?

Comment: Coming back to this question five years later, I have no idea why I used a shell script. I could've done exactly what I wanted in Python itself. ‍♂️

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In:

```
cmd1
cmd2
```

or

```
cmd1; cmd2
```

They are executed sequentially.

In

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

Or

```
cmd1 || cmd2
```

They are executed sequentially but whether `cmd2` is executed at all depends on whether `cmd1` succeeds (for `&&`) or fails (for `||`).

In

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

or

```
cmd1 & cmd2
cmd1 |& cmd2 # ksh
coproc cmd1; cmd2 # bash/zsh
```

or

```
cmd1 <(cmd2) # ksh/zsh/bash (also yash though with a different meaning)
```

They are executed concurrently. In the first case, some shells only wait for `cmd2` before carrying on with the rest of the script while some wait for both. In the second case, shells only wait for `cmd2` (`cmd1` is said to be run asynchronously (or in background when run in an interactive shell)) and in the third for `cmd1` (`cmd2` asynchronous).

In:

```
< "$(cmd1)" x=$(cmd2) y=$(cmd3) cmd4 "$(cmd5)" > "$(cmd6)"
```

Commands are run sequentially, but the order depends on the shell. In any case, `cmd4` will be executed last.

In:

```
cmd1 =(cmd2) # zsh
```

They are executed sequentially (`cmd2` first).

Note that in all those cases, any of those commands could start other processes. The shell would have no knowledge of them so can't possibly wait for them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is correct.
Consider this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    sleep 1
    echo "Slept 1"
    echo "Exit status $?, ok."
    sleep 1
    echo "Slept 1, now executing faulty command 'ps q'"
    ps q
    echo "Exit status $?, not ok. Loop continues forever..."
done
```

...will look like this when executed:

```
./loop.sh 
Slept 1
Exit status 0, ok.
Slept 1, now executing faulty command 'ps q'
ps: illegal option -- q
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-u]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
Exit status 1, not ok. Loop continues forever...
Slept 1
Exit status 0, ok.
Slept 1, now executing faulty command 'ps q'
ps: illegal option -- q
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-u]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
Exit status 1, not ok. Loop continues forever...
^C
```

As long as the loop is always `true` it does not matter which exit codes the programs inside the loop have. They will continue to execute in the sequence they are written.

> Is doing it like this efficient? Is there a better way to do it?

The **best** way to do it would be to squash the bug in your Python program!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question: Yes, commands in a shell script are executed synchronously in sequence, so the shell is blocked while your Python script is running.

It certainly would be better to fix the source of the error, but if that's not an option a shell script that will try to run the python script until it returns a zero status code (`while true;do ./script.py; if [[ "$?" = 0]];break;done`) is a sensible approach.

Comment: Note that programs exist that start threads or childs to continue in the background.